# Fetch fewer fields using find in waterline/sails

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sails.js, waterline

Currently when I run following command

```
User.find({quality:'good'}).exec(function(err, users){console.log(users)})
```

All the user fields are fetched. What if I just want 1 field like id of the *good* users?

```
select id from user where quality='good'
```

corresponding sql query. Whats the waterline equivalent query of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [waterline documentation](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/queries/query-language.md#select) you can do:

```
User.find({where: {quality:'good'}}, select: ['id'] });
```